# MathJax does not render all tex expression

Tags: latex, mathjax, tex

I have setup MathJax on a application that shows research documents and it works 99% fine with the `TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML` configuration.

The only issue is that on some rare documents the \varvec expression is not rendered and it's formatted in red.

[image: tex expression in red]

I am not a Tex expert and I haven't found anything about this to understand if it's a wrong tex expression or if there is some more configuration to set in MathJax

Comment: `\varvec` is not a standard command in LaTeX. It may be defined by a different package as a symbol, or perhaps it's a macro that takes (a number of) argument(s). Without more context it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This macro is not supported out of the box.

A full list of macros and environments supported by MathJax can be found at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands. MathJax aims to support all basic math mode macros but cannot support all possible macros out of the box.

However, you can write your own macros, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros. For more complex packages, you can write your own extensions, cf. also http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/ThirdParty.html#mathjax-third-party-extension-repository. Since MathJax is not TeX it cannot import TeX packages (such as sty files) so complex packages usually have to be re-implemented in its extension system.